# After adding related directory into path, I still can't execute the command in other directories

Tags: windows, command-line

So I have added the related directory into the path in my cmd context (not in the registry or environment variable). But the command is still not available for me in other directories. The following screen shot demonstrate what I mean:

[image]

I can also paste the related commands and results here:

> C:>cd "Program Files"\sfdx\bin
>
> C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin>path "%path%;%cd%"
>
> C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin>path
>   PATH="C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\;C:\installed\ffmpeg-20160531-git-a1953d4-win64-static\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Lance.shi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Lance.shi\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Program
>   Files\sfdx\bin"
>
> C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin>pushd \Lance
>
> C:\Lance>sfdx
>
> 'sfdx' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Lance>popd
>
> C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin>sfdx
>
> Usage: sfdx COMMAND
>
> Help topics, type sfdx help TOPIC for more details:
>
> force    tools for the Salesforce developer  plugins  manage plugins 
>   update   update CLI
>
> C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin>

Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Please do not post images of text, it makes it difficult for people to both search and copy-paste to try to help you. Please edit your question with the text (formatted as code preferably) instead of the image. Use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as `code/data/output/errorMsgs`. For more info see  [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Comment: What does `pushd \Lance && where sfdx` show?

Comment: @ottomeister where is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: :-(  What version of Windows are you running this on?  Can you do `pushd \Lance && dir sfdx*` ?  I'm trying to see whether there's a bogus executable in `\Lance` that is taking precedence over the real executable on `%PATH%` (the command shell always looks in the current directory before searching `%PATH%`.) Also, what happens if you do `cd \ && sfdx` ?

Comment: @ottomeister I am using Windows 10. I have just asked our helpdesk team to set the system variable for path to include that directory and it is working now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you should simply have closed and reopened cmd.exe after you added the paths.

Comment: Double quotes should never be in `PATH`.

Comment: @eryksun May I know why?

Comment: The Windows runtime library searches `PATH` by splitting the string on semicolon and handling each element as a literal name. Double quote is invalid in filenames because it's the `DOS_DOT` wildcard character, one of 5 file-system wildcard characters, which also includes less-than (`<`) for `DOS_STAR`, greater than (`>`) for `DOS_QM`, asterisk (`*`), and question mark (`?`).  WinAPI `FindFirstFile` follows an algorithm to transform a given DOS wildcard pattern to one that uses the `DOS_` values in addition to `*` and `?`, so the filesystem can emulate how MS-DOS worked.

Comment: The CMD shell is an odd duck (as usual) that does its own thing. It implements a search for files that works better with how it uses `PATHEXT` in addition to `PATH`. CMD interprets double quotes to disable ";" parsing, so if you quote the whole `PATH` value you've effectively turned it all into one element. Moreover, CMD's special handling of double quotes in `PATH` shouldn't be relied on because most system components rely on the runtime library's search, which doesn't allow directory names that include semicolon and handles double quote as a literal character.